# Can I install Node.js modules from my own server?

Tags: node.js, npm

Let's say I have an own server and on the server I have Node.js modules. How can I install these Node modules? Is there global configuration file where I can add my own server? Or can I define my server in an user configuration file in my current Node project? Or is there a parameter like `-server` which I can add to `npm install myownmodule`? I want to keep my module private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [point to a tarball url](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

Running `npm pack` will create the tarball, which you can put on your server and then install it via:

`npm install <tarball url>`

Running your own private npm repo with [verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio) is pretty straightforward too if you'd prefer that route. You can set up `.npmrc` to publish scoped packages to your own repo instead of npmjs, etc.

Associating a [scope with a registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc#comments) looks like this:

```
; Set a new registry for a scoped package
@myscope:registry=https://mycustomregistry.example.org
```

Just replace `https://mycustomregistry.example.org` with wherever verdaccio is running.

Docs:
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#scope